# Rails - Heroku - Git - Problems connecting to repo with os x 10.6.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, https, heroku

I am trying to clone git repo to my local with terminal runnin OS X 10.6.5 and it seems like I am getting a connection error when I do: "git clone git@heroku.com:APPNAME.git /my/path". It says "Read from socket failed: connection reset by peer".  I have created a key and everything, it's just a problem with connecting and reading.

I have searched about this problem and it appears that it is possible that I am behind a firewall that is preventing me from pulling up the repo. I have tried to get the repo using the HTTPS method instead but I don't think I am getting the URL right because it gives me "fatal: HTTP request failed" when I try "git clone https://git.heroku.com/APPNAME.git". I am not sure if that is the right URL or if heroku even supports HTTPS.

I have submitted a ticket to heroku so I am waiting on that as well.  If anyone knows how to get the repo with https method from heroku I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the git URL for your app is available from the my apps page in the Heroku website console.

Also I'm pretty sure that git clone runs over SSH which by it's name is 'secure'

Comment: He's asking for a "Smart HTTP" URL, not a `git:` URL. E.g., on GitHub, you can do either `https://github.com/me/myProject.git` or `git://github.com/me/myProject.git`. Heroku's console, AFAICS, shows only the latter form. He's asking for the former form, which is *considerably* easier to use when corporate firewalls, etc., are involved.